# Ruby SIP requests

Tags: ruby, sip

I have been tasked with sending alert messages via SIP (Session Initiation Protocol). I use Ruby (on Rails).

I have seen [How to send ‘SIP request‘ (SIP client) in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56628191/how-to-send-sip-request-sip-client-in-java) and it appears it is just about streaming a string over a UDP socket. Am I correct?

Does anyone know of any good Gems that could support this? I have looked at several but they tend to be SIP servers rather than clients / senders.
e.g.: https://github.com/turboladen/sdp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could just use some already existing solution and run a command-line client from Ruby that does the work for you.

Here I found an SDK library with a command-line interface:
https://sipsimpleclient.org/

Here's their example of sending a message with their command-line interface:
https://docs-new.sipthor.net/w/sip_clients/sip_message/

Sending a message like this could then be accomplished with a simple Ruby `system` call.

```
system('sip-message [..account options..] -m "Hello World"')
```